# MS charts not displaying properly on win 2008 server

Tags: asp.net

I am displaying two line graphs and two pie charts on my web page. I am not sure why is it happening, but sometimes I see the charts when I run my applications and sometimes I don't. below is my web.confg file settings.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="ANALYST"/>
          <deny users="*" />

        </authorization>
        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
          <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />

        </handlers>


      </system.webServer>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="WebDevServerUseConfigSettings=true;privateImages=false;storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\test\;"/>
      </appSettings>
```

apart of this, I have System.web.datavisualization.dll in my bin folder and I am running the application on window server 2008 R2. The whole application is devleoped in .net 4.0. I am not getting any error message. I see the graphs images in the C:\Test folder where I am putting the images, but not on the web page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the browser caching issue. If I clean the browser cache, it works fine.